# Navbar collapse link doesn't work sometimes on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, navbar

My Collapse / Navbar is works well in other devices but it is not working in my iPhone or Ipads. I am using botstrap3.

Can any one help me to resolve this problem.

my code is

```
<a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="font-size:30px;">
<span class="nb_left pull-left">
           <span class="fa fa-reorder"></span>
</span>               
</a>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are some issues discussed which states that these kind of problem arise. I have found that it might be the issue of a missing `href="#"` inside anchor tag.

For instance this might work:

```
<a href="#" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="font-size:30px;">
                <span class="nb_left pull-left">
                    <span class="fa fa-reorder"></span></span>
            </a>
```

[Source: Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7447)

Answer (score 0):

try media query in css ..it makes the design responsive so that u can easily run on your iphone